# TypeError: 0, _firestore.collection is not a function (it is undefined)

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using React Native and trying to query my firestore database. I was originally using < v9 syntax, but that doesn't support `or` queries. so I'm trying to use the updated modular syntax for this specific file, and I keep getting the error "TypeError: 0, _firestore.collection is not a function (it is undefined)." I'm essentially trying to query all of the documents in my collection to find matches of a string in two fields.

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import { UserContext } from '../UserContext';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import { or, query, where, collection, doc, getDoc } from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../../services/firebase';


export const MatchesContext = createContext();

export const MatchesProvider = (props) => {

  const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);
  const { userId } = useContext(UserContext); // Get userId directly from UserContext
  const matchesRef = collection(db, "matches");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userId) return;

    // Use the or query to get matches for the current user
    const matchesQuery = query(
      matchesRef,  
      or(
        where('user1ID', '==', userId),
        where('user2ID', '==', userId)
      )
    );
```

If I switch to a single query instead of compound and use v8 syntax, it works. All of my other db reads also work. Any idea what could be happening/how I can fix this? TIA